# [Solved]Powershell Script to HardLink Multiple files from Source to Target Folder

Tags: powershell, arraylist, hardlink

I am not able to understand if I need an Array, how to set it up in Powershell and if i need something like for and stuff, since I'm not a developer and never dived into it too deep.
So what I want to achieve, is to create HardLinks from Files in a Source Folder, into a Targetfolder and have this as a powershell script later.
Since I want to safe Diskspace, I would prefer to create a HardLink instead of Copy Paste and having the files eating Diskspace.
As example:
Sourcefolder has -N files
All shall be read into the array(?) to automize the hardlink creation.
I already tried the hardlink creation with the New-Item element like shown below, but I always get the error, that the path can't be found, despite the path exists...

I'm clueless and I hope someone can help me there.

```
$source = "C:\temp1"
$target = "C:\temp2"
$filename = "" #Array filled variable with content from $source folder

Array.....

New-Item -Type HardLink -Path "$source\$filename" -Value "$target\$filename #Tried it and ends with Errors in Path not found. Don't understand why
```

Tested on Win 10 Pro 22H2 if it is necessary

Tried to create the powershell command for the hardlink creation and failed.

I would also accept cmd commandlets, if that's easier to generate and understand.

Comment: You probably just need to loop through it. So line 3 becomes `$filenames = ""` and then later `ForEach($filename in $filenames){New-Item -Type HardLink -Path "$source\$filename" -Value "$target\$filename"}`